# IIS8 PHP Issue MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am having an issue getting PHP to work with MSSQL on a IIS8 server.

I have the extensions loaded for PHP 5.4 php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll and php_sql_srv_54_ts.dll

In `phpinfo()` I get:

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"
```

I have done a ton of searching, and have configured everything accordingly.

How can I get MSSQL to work properly with PHP?

The only reason I know it's not is a codeigniter install is completely blank... and I know from previous installs it's a db connection issue

Note: PHPinfo, also does NOT show the sqlsrv sections it should be with the extensions enabled...

Simple PDO Debug testing:

```
$dsn = "mssql:host=localhost;dbname=THE_DB";
$user = "MY_UN";
$password = "MY_PW";                        
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    var_dump($dbh);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

produces the following error:

```
object(PDOException)#2 (8) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(21) "could not find driver"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(35) "D:\Domains\TurboKits Admin\test.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(13)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
   array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(35) "D:\Domains\TurboKits Admin\test.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(13)
      ["function"]=>
      string(11) "__construct"
      ["class"]=>
      string(3) "PDO"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(3) {
       [0]=>
       string(44) "mssql:host=localhost;dbname=MY_DB"
        [1]=>
        string(10) "MY_UN"
        [2]=>
        string(10) "MY_PW"
      }
    }
 }
 ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
  ["errorInfo"]=>
  NULL
 }
```

Comment: yes, one second, I'll update the question

Comment: p.s.  Nothing in the error logs